# Android, retain values in Singleton for Background service

Tags: android, singleton, intentservice

I have an intentService in my application that is scheduled to be called every 5 minutes. In that service I am using values shared with the rest of the app (Strings, int..). I am using Singleton to hold these values. This works fine most of the times.

However sometimes, for no reason (at least that I can see), the values are lost, and the app crashes due to that. It seems that the Singleton looses it state.

I have read that Android can delete information from memory that it finds unnecessary. For this reason in my activities, I have saved the values in a bundle when the app goes idle (onPause and onResume).

Now the problem is that in the intentService the case is different. I am calling the service every 5 minutes using a timer.

I need a way to retain the values in the singleton. I would rather not save them in the database (it seems a heavy task to do this every 5 minutes), there should be a simpler way.

I hope that was clear, I am grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I doubt, as you use Singleton class in your application, might be android kill your application instance on memory low scenario. So you can lost your singleton class object also. Instead of this, I suggest you have to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: so with SharedPreference I can make sure that information is not lost? Can I alter SharedPreference afterwards?

Comment: Yes, Your information will remain stored until your application is not removed from device or on cache clear (I have confusion on this). And you can modify your shared preference data, Its act like map with key - value pairs. Just stored in some file in application data directory.

Answer (score 2):

If your process is terminated by the system, all the data in memory will be lost. You cannot rely on your process being alive all the time so that you can keep that data in your singleton. Either store that data in a [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db), store it in [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), or [save it to a file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) that you can read from the next time your singleton is initialized.